# which mime type to use ,to attach ".zip" file in Gmail 

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to attach a ".zip" file and send the email using Gmail Service.

I am using below code to do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(application/x-compressed);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{abc@gmail.com});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,         
Uri.parse(abc.zip);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello..");
```

If I use the "application/x-compressed" mime type , I am able to send ".zip" attachments but I am unable launch Gmail composer directly, before that it is providing list of options.

If I use "message/rfc822" mime type, I am able to launch Gmail composer directly, but unable to attach ".zip" files.

Pl. help me to how to combine these two mime types in a single intent object.
Pl. let me know if there's any alternative to do this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -

```
intent.setType("application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip")
```

Mime type found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027582/3090120)

Answer (score -1):

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

to open Gmail directly. however if gmail is not installed it will cause exception, ActivityNotFound

Answer (score -2):

I am using this code and works. check this:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"Example@gmail.com"});        
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject//@@");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message//@@");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("sdcard/1.zip");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```