# How to send Zip file from sdcard to mail in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi friends,

I need to send zip file as attachment to email. I have tried using code below. However, I receive email message without the attachment. What am I doing wrong?

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button email;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"radha@impressol.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email Message");
            intent.setType("application/zip");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,        Uri.parse("file://+/sdcard/zipname.zip"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

        }
    });
}

  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371065/android-share-zip-file-via-gmail?lq=1 check here

Comment: thanks for reply..but u sent second link,like that only i also  i gave path..

Comment: Why do you have a "+" *within* the quoted Uri string?  If you are meaning to build a string from smaller ones, use an unquoted +, however when those parts are both constant strings, you can just merge them.

Comment: thanks... Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/zipname.zip")); i gave like that..now its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case remove the "+" from Uri string.

P.S. it'll also work without Uri protocol, like `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/zipname.zip");`